# Google Photo - Download using REST API

Tags: java, android, rest, google-oauth

Trying to just make the REST request using the web browser.
Using: https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search?

Tried key=clientID
Tried access=clientID
etc...

Get ERROR text with: "Request is missing required authentication credential."

With my client ID fails. What's the syntax for this?

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

hi Patrick i think you are missing https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#specify_your_apps_client_id Client ID try to follow the  documentation